# variadic multidimensional array

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array, variadic-templates

Could I call a multidimensional array like

```
func(0,0,0); //=> if I know it's dimension on the run time. 
func(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0); //=> if I know it's dimension on the run time.
```

through help of the variadic templates

instead of:

```
data[0][0][0];
data[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0];
```

Comment: You want to create an array, or get an element from it?

Comment: More details or a use case would be helpful.  Not really sure why/what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work but instead of doing `data[1][2][3]` you will have to use `indexed(data,1,2,3)`

It works for `plain arrays` as well as `std::arrays`. You can extend it `std::vector` just by duplicating the specializations. (*I think it should work for any thing that overloads operator[] but not sure.*)

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t dim>
struct getTypeAtDim { typedef T type; };

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct getTypeAtDim<T[N],1> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T, size_t dim, size_t N>
struct getTypeAtDim<T[N],dim> : getTypeAtDim< T, dim-1> {};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct getTypeAtDim<std::array<T,N>,1> { typedef T type; };

template<typename T, size_t dim, size_t N>
struct getTypeAtDim<std::array<T,N>,dim> : getTypeAtDim< T, dim-1> {};

template<typename T, size_t dim>
using typeAtDim = typename getTypeAtDim<T, dim>::type;

template<typename T> 
typeAtDim<T,1>&
indexed(T& arr, const int& first) {
    return arr[first];
}

template<typename T, typename... Args> 
typeAtDim<T,sizeof...(Args) + 1>& 
indexed(T& arr, const int& first, const Args& ...rest) {
    return indexed(arr[first],rest...);
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    std::array<int,2> a1 = {1,2};
    std::array<int,2> a2 = {3,4};
    std::array<std::array<int,2>,2> a = {a1,a2};
    std::array<std::array<std::array<int,2>,2>,2> c = {a,a};
    int b[2][2] = {{5,6},{7,8}};


    std::cout << indexed(a,1,1) << std::endl;
    indexed(a,1,1) = 5;
    std::cout << indexed(a,1,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << indexed(b,1,1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << indexed(c,1,1,1) << std::endl;
    indexed(c,1,1) = a1;
    std::cout << indexed(c,1,1,1) << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
4 5 8 4 2
```

---

[**`Here is a test run`**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d49d17f578e8679d9b9e6584f388317f-361761a79a4e1e122999571b14caa207).

---

I am not using `auto` with `trailing return types` because **the variadic version of `indexed` will not match itself when deducing the type of the return**. So until that gets resolved with `gcc` you will have to use something like this.

Comment: @Avatar Glad it helped. Actually I might even use it myself. Easier than doing [][] all the time in generated code. So thank you too for bringing up the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can overload operator(). I am not sure if it is going to help you a lot.

If you are using C++11 you may think creatively about using initializer_list.