# C++ return type deduction with variadic template on binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, operator-keyword, return-type, auto

Imagine you have a simple composite structure like a binary tree and on the root you want to be able to automaticaly get either node or leaf by something like :

```
template <typename... Args>
auto operator()(Args...);
```

Allowing to :

```
auto node_or_leaf = root()(1, 2, 3);
```

Or :

```
Node node = root()(1, 2);
Leaf leaf = root()(1, 2, 3);
```

I already can do the job with this syntax, but this is not return type deducing.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> operator()(Args...);
```

And that need some template specialization to work. And i'm not sure that this syntax works on differents compiler (work on MSVC2017):

```
auto leaf = root->operator()<Leaf>(1, 2, 3);
```

I'm not really warned about C++14/17 capabilities, so I need your help if you want. And I thank you by advance.

Comment: So you want `root()` to either return a node or a leaf depending on the parameters passed?

Comment: @Rakete Yes, and if possible by using automatic return type deduction. Something like this : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675654/variadic-multidimensional-array)

Comment: But then the parameters can't be known at runtime, because C++ is a static language. How do I know whether `2, 4, 5` is a leaf or node?

Comment: This is why I ask you if something is possible. Even with exception throwing for the '`out_of_range`' indexes. The idea is that to have a easy access. Basically, this is not for a public access but for an internal code.

Comment: Is the tree a compile-time structure or a runtime one? Type must be determined at compile-time, from information known at compile time (unless you want to return `variant` or use some other runtime dispatch).

Comment: @Useless - at runtime. So if understand, auto & decltype are only available for compile-time structure. Note that the structure is based on `std::vector` with composite around a base class that can hold or not derived classes. I already can do the job at runtime but I just want to hide the `typename T` of the return class for an undetermined `auto` with an conditionnal casting in the variadic template unfolding.

Comment: So you must use runtime dispatch, not compile time dispatch. You either need an `if` in the client code (handling a different type in each branch), or a visitor-style dispatch (you provide a different callback overload for each type, and the container forwards to the right one)